# How to define loading order of external CSS with extension and site package

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

I have an own extension with a CSS link in `HeaderAssets` section of a fluid template to load an external CSS file. This works fine.

Now I want to overwrite some CSS details of the extension inside one site package w/o the use of `!important` feature but the proper order of loaded CSS files:

- **at first:** extensions CSS files
- **at second:** site package CSS files

How can I force TYPO3 v10 to load the CSS files (or extensions) in my wanted order?

Changing the order in "Include static (from extensions)" does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include the extensions typoscript via the backend but via the sitepackage by

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT
```

For every typoscript setup and constants file needed. So in the backend include only the typoscript for your sitepackage.

Then you can choose the order however you want.

I put the constants and typoscipt of each extension in an own subfolder of a folder Extensions.
For example xxxx_sitepackage/Configuration/TypoScript/Extensions/News. 2 files: _Constants.typoscriptc (with the include_typoscript to the original constants file of news) and Setup.typoscript:

```
 <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:news/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt">

plugin.tx_news {
    settings {
       cssFile >
       #etc.
```

Then:

```
 <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:EXT:xxxx_sitepackage/Configuration/TypoScript/Extensions" extensions="typoscript">
```

Also almost every extension has a typoscript setting which includes the JS and CSS. You could also disable them and load them / bundle them with Gulp, Laravel Mix, whatever. So you get only 1 CSS and 1 JS file. Or you let TYPO3 do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new syntax since TYPO3 9:

```
@import 'EXT:news/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt'
```

Take a look at
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Includes.html

for all variants.