# TYPO3 - images & videos in fileadmin don't display

Tags: html, video, typo3

I have a problem with uploading my images and videos in TYPO3.

I use TYPO3 ver. 10.4.21 and some Extensions: Sitepackage Builder, pizpalue and Fluid_styled_content.

I uploaded my mp4 videos in fileadmin (in `user_uplaod`), but the videos can't be shown anywhere else.

On the fileadmin you can see:
[image]

I added a content element of "Text&Media" to test:
[image]

I don't get any errors, but my video and image doesn't be displayed on my page.

How can I resolve this problem to show my videos and images on my page?

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: IMO TYPO3 is not able to generate preview images from videos.

Comment: @Julian Hofmann
I see, then I got it why I can't watch or display the preview my videos by the fileadmin. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason why I couldn't see my images, if I added a content with text&media of fluid_styled_content.

It was easy.... I didn't include the extension "fluid_styled_content" into my root.

[image]

Comment: Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270315/how-to-define-loading-order-of-external-css-with-extension-and-site-package/68271007 and not load extension typoscript anymore via the backend (except for your config extension).