# not work a path to template of typoscript after fluid_styled_content by TYPO3

Tags: path, typo3, typoscript

I made a stupid mistake and I can't resolve it....so I need your help.

I created a custom content element in a extension `sitepackage builder` by TYPO3 ver. 10.4.21.
I included the sitepackage builder and started creating a custom content element.

But **I had forgotten to include the extension `fluid_styled_content`**!

Without the `fluid_styled_content`, I can see my contents which I created with sitepackage builder. But I can't see other contents of `fluid_styled_content`, because I didn't include it.

Now I included the `fluid_styled_content`, then I got an error: "Oops, an error occurred! Code: 2021120214173488065165" I think the typoscript don't render my template anymore....

I tried to change my path, but it didn't work with my methode. I'll write my codes and what I did here:

1. I added `fluid_styled_content` at first:

[image]

2. gave path:

in `/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript`

```
# Path to Templates, Partials, Layouts
lib.contentElement {
  templateRootPaths {
    100 = EXT:mein_projektarbeit/Resources/Private/Templates/
  }
  partialRootPaths {
    100 = EXT:mein_projektarbeit/Resources/Private/Partials/
  }
  layoutRootPaths {
    100 = EXT:mein_projektarbeit/Resources/Private/Layouts/
  }
  dataProcessing {
            20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
            20 {
                levels = 2
                includeSpacer = 1
                as = mainnavigation
            }
  }
}

# add content elements
@import 'EXT:mein_projektarbeit/Configuration/TypoScript/ContentElements/*.typoscript'
@import 'EXT:mein_projektarbeit/Configuration/TypoScript/Helper/'
```

in `/Configuration/TypoScript/ContentElements/OneColumnFlipbox.typoscript`

```
tt_content {
   oneColumnFlipbox_newcontentelement =< lib.contentElement
   oneColumnFlipbox_newcontentelement {
      templateName = OneColumnFlipbox
   }
}
```

Then my path don't show up:
[image]

3. I commented a row in setup.typoscript:
   [image]

But the path didn't show up and the error "Oops, an error occurred!" is on my page....

How can I give a path in typoscript? Or where/what should I write codes more?

I hope anyone can help me....
Because I don't understand much about typoscript/TYPO3, I can't make it by myself..

---

Adding:
I could display my contents of fluid_styled_content just to add some codes in typoscript:

```
30 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\GalleryProcessor
    30 {
        maxGalleryWidth = {$styles.content.textmedia.maxW}
        maxGalleryWidthInText = {$styles.content.textmedia.maxWInText}
        columnSpacing = {$styles.content.textmedia.columnSpacing}
        borderWidth = {$styles.content.textmedia.borderWidth}
        borderPadding = {$styles.content.textmedia.borderPadding}
    }
```

But this is just for a textmedia.
I have another extension "pizpalue". Now I can't render the content elements of bootstrap like timeline and a error coems up `ERROR: Content Element with uid "476" and type "timeline" has no rendering definition!`

I didn't include pizpalue or bootstrap, but the wizards of bootstrap are displayed (like timeline). So I thought I can use them. I think I have to add some rendering for pizpalue or bootstrap as extension in typoscript. (I added a Bootstrap as framework by includeCSS and so on. before that.)

I can't understand why textmedia and so on had automatically included in tt_content, but no timeline... I did't add anything for ce_column2 and so on....From where comes ce_column2 or other things? And why didn't timeline be shown up?

[image]

Like fluid_styled_content can I add a rendering with dataprocessing? Or is there a best way?

I saw some codes like:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:news/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt">

plugin.tx_news {
    settings {
       cssFile >
       #etc.
```

But I don't know where/what exactly I should write...

Answer (score 1):

See [How to define loading order of external CSS with extension and site package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270315/how-to-define-loading-order-of-external-css-with-extension-and-site-package/68271007)

And load constants and typoscript templates with your sitepackage extension.

Regarding your question, just add the constants in a constants template for Fluid Template:

```
styles.templates {
   templateRootPath = {$paths.extTmplPath}fluid_styled_content/Templates/
   partialRootPath = {$paths.extTmplPath}fluid_styled_content/Partials/
   layoutRootPath = {$paths.extTmplPath}fluid_styled_content/Layouts/
}
```

And define `{$paths.extTmplPath}` like for example as `EXT:mein_projektarbeit/Resources/Private/Extensions/`

Tip: for a good start of your sitepackage check out https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I couldn't understand well... where do I have to write `plugin.tx_news {
    settings {
       cssFile >
       #etc.`? and `<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:EXT:xxxx_sitepackage/Configuration/TypoScript/Extensions" extensions="typoscript">`?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the order of the included typoscript statics.

As FSC installs the basic rendering it initializes a lot of typoscript values. Probably your values too.
Move your static include after the includes of FSC. then inspect the values you have set.

A hint for debugging:
look into the `Template Analyzer` where you can see the order of typoscript. Especially if you show the whole typoscript (Button `View the complete TS Listing`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try it.